# PowerMockito and Mockito conflict

Tags: junit, mockito, powermockito

I need to built unit tests (with junit) for a legacy system. The method that I need to test, makes use of a static method and I need to check if it's called. So, I'll need to use PowerMockito (for "regular" mocking, we use mockito).

But, when I include PowerMockito statements inside the test, Mockito fails with an `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException`. If I comment the lines `PowerMockito.mockStatic(Application.class), PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Application.class) and PowerMockito.verifyStatic()`, the UnfinishedStubbingExceptiondoes does not occur, but this way, I'm not able to check if my IllegalArgumentException occured.

The method under test looks like:

```
public class ClientMB {

   public void loadClient(Client client) {
      try {
         if (client == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Client is mandatory!");
         }

         setClient(clientService.findById(client.getId()));
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         Application.handleException(ex);
      }
   }
}
```

And the test looks like:

```
@PrepareForTest({ Application.class })
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ClientMBTest {

   @Test
   public final void testLoadClient() {
      ClientService mockedClientService = Mockito.mock(ClientService.class);
      Mockito.when(mockedClientService.findById(42L)).thenReturn(new Client());

      PowerMockito.mockStatic(Application.class);
      PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Application.class);

      ClientMB cmb = new ClientMB(mockedClientService);
      mb.loadClient(null);

      PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
   }
}
```

I imported PowerMokito using the latest version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Application.class);
```

That's a *stubbing* command, but [because you don't make a *method call* after the `when(...)`, it's *unfinished*](http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.6.2/org/powermock/api/mockito/expectation/PowerMockitoStubber.html#when-java.lang.Class-).

```
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Application.class);
Application.someApplicationMethod();
```

You need to use this syntax because the normal `doVerb().when(foo)` syntax will provide an *instance*, and Java often issues a warning when trying to call a static method based on an instance instead of a class name.

If you want to stub *all of Application's methods*, you can do so by passing another argument into `mockStatic`:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Application.class, RETURNS_SMART_NULLS);
```